# Upgrading tika-app from 1.28.1 to 1.28.2 (or greater) generates invalid .xlsx files

Tags: groovy, jmeter, zip, apache-poi, apache-tika

I have groovy code in JMeter 5.5 which takes an Excel template and then populates it with data.

Due to security vulnerabilities in the tika-app lib we've been asked to upgrade to a newer version of tika-app.

However, when we upgrade to a tika-app version greater than 1.28.1 our code generates the excel file but the system under tests fails validation on the Excel file.

It states that the 'The selected filetype is invalid.  Please upload a valid .xlsx or .csv file and try again.'

When stepping through a debugger I see that the actual error appears to be `Bad signature (0x00000A2E) at position  0x000001E4`.  However, I'm not exactly sure what to do about this.

I tried the following.  Given JMeter 5.5 comes with tika-core and tika-parsers 1.28.3 I updated the tika-app lib in the JMeter /lib directory to tika-app-1.28.3.jar.

I expected that the jump from 1.28.1 to 1.28.3 would not produce any regressions in our Excel file generation.  By trying different libs I was able to find that some change in 1.28.2 appeared to lead to the regression.  Here is the list of changes: https://issues.apache.org/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-printable/temp/SearchRequest.html?jqlQuery=project+%3D+TIKA+AND+fixVersion+%3D+1.28.2&tempMax=100.  When looking at the change list I assume it was one of the Apache POI upgrades but I don't know that for certain.

I unzipped the generated .xlsx files from both 1.28.1 and 1.28.3 and looked for diffs in the files.

I found the following:

- The .xlsx files from both 1.28.1 and 1.28.3 both open fine in Excel.
- The unzipped files were almost identical except 1.28.1 created Excel files where columns had the attribute collapsed="false" explicity defined in \xl\worksheets\sheet2.xml and \xl\worksheets\sheet3.xml
- If I unzipped the .xlsx from 1.28.3 and did nothing but try to zip it again I got the zip error 'File not found or no read permission.'
- If I save the Excel file (make no changes) created in 1.28.3 it then gets 'fixed' and our software will see it as a valid .xlsx.

Any ideas about what may be going on or what to look at next?  I made no changes to my code.  Only change was upgrading the tika-app library in JMeter.  Thanks!

Comment: Given you're able to open the files in Excel without issues they're kind of valid so I'm under impression it's a bug in "our software"

Comment: I tend to agree at this point.  I'll implement the workaround until I can get the team responsible for this service to check their validation code.

Comment: The `Bad Signature` error looks very like  a problem with the Zip file (rather than the payload). Is there an example available online anywhere?

Comment: There's no example online to share however I did upload a copy to mega.io here: https://mega.nz/file/B2ITgZjR#f2OrODsEuUsIhegfvbxPI3FakawnraR9fZyYvBH3ZE4

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that might shed some light on the problem.  I noticed that the unzipped .xlsx files for the 1.28.3 file had no Date Modified attributes.

- Create the Excel file in 1.28.3
- Unzip it on Linux
- Simply touch all the unzip files using `find . -type f -exec touch {} +`
- Zip it back up via `zip -r touched.xlsx *`

At this point the new touched.xlsx file uploads and validates fine in our software.